# Calling bind() twice in a row

Tags: c, sockets

I was wondering, when creating a server, what would happen if you called bind() and then called bind() again without doing anything else in between.

Comment: I didn't try but it should give the error `EINVAL The socket is already bound to an address.`

Comment: I agree with @stark But why don't you try and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Per the linux man page, you'll get an:

```
   EINVAL The socket is already bound to an address.
```

which is based on the following standards:

```
   POSIX.1-2001,  POSIX.1-2008,  SVr4,  4.4BSD
```